# Use JavaScript to start YouTube search

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube

I am building a Search-Bar for a costume new-tab-page. The purpose is to do searches in multiple place, one of which is supposed to be YouTube.
I want to end up on YouTube and not use the API to return results.

I have a form layed out as such:

```
<form id="searchForm">
    <input name="q" type="text" value="" id="searchTerm-js">
</form>
```

The name of the input is q because default search is Google (already working).
When you type input and press "Return" a JavaScript function is called that is supposed to start the search.

```
    if(term.indexOf("!y ") > -1) {              //want to search youtube
        term = term.replace("!y ", "");         //take away the "command"
        form.action="http://youtube.com/result";//set URL
        $("#searchTerm-js").val(term);          //set what to search for
        $("#searchTerm-js").attr("name", "search_query"); //Change name of input
        form.method="GET";                      
        form.submit();                          //Do search
    }
```

Now I would expect to be directed to "youtube.com/result?search_query=term" where "term" is what I am searching for. (Successfully applied this to Google)
But I get directed to "youtube.com/user/result?search_query=term"?

Any ideas why this happens and how I could make this search work?

About DuckDuckGo: yeah I know that DuckDuckGo has a feature like that but I want to add more sites and use German Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo in the URL

`http://youtube.com/result`

should be:

`http://youtube.com/results`.

Comment: Thank you...
So the above is a way to do what I want, working fine now.